# MySQL query to get last 4 records of a related table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with two tables: `users` and `payment`s.
Each user has many payments and each payment can be successful or failed.

I need to write a query to get all the users who failed the last 4 payments.

This is what I tried so far:

```
select *
from users u
where u.id in(
    select p.user_id
    from payments
    where p.status = 'failed'
    group by p.user_id
    having count(p.id) = 4
);
```

But as you can see this is not only checking for the last 4 payments, but all of them. So, it is returning the users that have failed 4 payments (in global, not only the last 4).

I don't know if it is important but the fields on the tables are:

users:

```
id | name | email | password
```

payment:

```
id | date | status                     | user_id 
   |      | (can be success or failed) | (FK)
```

## Update:

This [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/936c6e/1/0) will help to understand what I need.

The query is returning all users with 4 failed payments. But I only need the users whose 4 most recent payments failed. In this case it will be only user with id 5

Comment: The question is bit ambiguous. Do you want the users whose last 4 payments were failed,or you want the users that involved in overall last 4 failed payments?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Harshil. I added a sqlfiddle to try to explain what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
    SELECT x.user_id, count(*) as cnt 
    FROM (
        SELECT a.user_id, a.date, a.status FROM payment AS a WHERE 
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM payment AS b 
             WHERE b.user_id = a.user_id AND b.date >= a.date) <= 4 
             ORDER BY a.user_id ASC, a.date DESC) AS x 
    WHERE x.status = 'failed' 
    GROUP BY x.user_id
    HAVING cnt >=4;
```

Comment: Thanks very much @user8715013! I was hitting my head against the keyboard to find a solution and this one is just perfect and performs very well (my payments table contains +1 million records and your query takes less than 5 seconds to execute).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the users, whose last 4 transactions were failed (only last 4, not total 4) then following query should get the job done:

```
      select u.* from users u
  where
  id in
    (select p.user_id from payment p
    where (select count(*) from payment p1
           where p.user_id = p1.user_id
           and      p.date <= p1.date            
           order by p1.user_id asc,p1.date desc
          ) <= 4
     and  p.status <> 'success'
     group by p.user_id
      having count(*)>=4);
```

check the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfd1ba/23/0)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. It is the second case: I need to get a list of users whose last 4 (most recent 4) payments failed. Unfortunately the query seems to consider all payments (not only the last 4). I updated some records in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfd1ba/1/0) just as example

Comment: Ok. Let me check

Comment: Hey! I've updated my query as well as sqlfiddle link. Can you please try it out?

Comment: Hi @Harshil! Thanks very much for your help. I've accepted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46548360/5471005) because its simplicity and performance.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the LIMIT keyword, and specify an ORDER.

Try this

```
select *
from users u
where u.id in(
    select p.user_id
    from payments
    where p.status = 'failed'
    group by p.user_id
    having count(p.id) = 4
) ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 4;
```

Not entirely sure what you are trying to do inside the WHERE statement, but `ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 4`  will retrieve the four most recent rows.

Comment: shouldn't it be DESC?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
select users.id, users.name, users.email, users.password
from users 
left join (
    select p1.id, p1.date, p1.status, p1.user_id,             
        count(p2.id) seq  -- this count() creates a sequence number for each user ordered by date
    from payment p1
    left join payment p2
      on p1.user_id = p2.user_id    -- here I set sequence for each user
     and p1.date <= p2.date         -- here I set sequence is ordered by data
    group by p1.id, p1.date, p1.status, p1.user_id
    ) t
  on users.id = t.user_id
where t.seq < 5  -- Now filter last 4 sequences of each user's payments
  and t.status = 'failed' 
group by users.id, users.name, users.email, users.password
having count(*) = 4; -- At last filter those have 4 failed in last 4 sequences
```

**[[ SQL Fiddle Demo ]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c2e70/2)**